# Sequelize associations will not work

Tags: node.js, database-design, sequelize.js

So I've recently started using Sequelize and am mucking around with it at the moment. I have two models (`User` & `Photo`) Basically the what I'm trying to do is do a `findAll` from `user` and `include: [ { model: 'photo' } ]` so that I get all the photos that the particular user submitted.

User model:

```
var user = sequelize.define(configModels.user, {
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      referenceces: {
        model: 'photo',
        key: 'userId'
      }

    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          user.hasMany(models.photo, { as: 'photo_fk', constraints: true });
        }
    }, 
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
  });
```

Photo model:

```
var photo = sequelize.define(configModels.photo, {
    photoId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      referenceces: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'userId'
      }
    }, 
    photo: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          photo.belongsTo(models.user, { as: 'user_fk', constraints: true });
        }
    },
    freezeTableName: true // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
  });
```

Here is where I am running the `findAll` method:

```
User.findAll({
        include: [
            { model: 'photo' }
        ]
    }).then(function(users){
        console.log("Found all ids: ", users);
        // callback(users);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
});
```

When I run this I get an error saying the two models are not associated?! Like so:

`[Error: X is not associated to Y!]`

Comment: Try to include not a string, but a Model. `include: [
            { model: photo }
        ]`

Comment: Had already tried that with no luck @Adam

Comment: `include: [
            { model: photo, as: 'photo_fk' }
        ]` ?